# How to restrict max textarea width and height in chrome or how to disable textarea resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, textarea

Chrome allowed to resize text area by drugging that on the bottom right corner, but some times this movement may break design of the page, so i am wondering how to restrict the max and min width for that action of how to disable that function at all with `thml/javascript/css` on the page?

Comment: you can use `CSS` - `max-width` and `max-height`

Comment: You shouldn't use `resize: none` unless you *absolutely* must. It's really very annoying indeed not to be able to resize tiny little `textarea`s.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can disable re-sizing it with the following css:

```
resize: none;
```

Answer (score 37):

you can use :

```
resize: vertical; 
max-height: 200px;
```

Comment: the best solution for me!

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Disabling the resizing completely is really frustration for the user, you should be able to at-least resize vertically to some extent/

Comment: I'm here because that doesn't work. Using material design matInput (Angular)

Answer (score 25):

You can also restrict to horizontal resizing only with:

```
resize: horizontal;
```

and only vertical resizing with:

```
resize: vertical;
```

Answer (score 18):

This is all a matter of CSS.
To disable the resizing (drag thumb) just use `resize: none;`. To restrict size `max(min)-width` and `height` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```css
textarea.vertical {
  resize: vertical;
  max-height: 130px;
  min-height: 80px;
}

textarea.horizontal {
  resize: horizontal;
  max-width: 130px;
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>Horizontally resizable textarea</p>
<textarea type="text" class="horizontal"></textarea>
<br>
<p>Vertically resizable textarea</p>
<textarea type="text" class="vertical"></textarea>
```

You can set the resize property as horizontal and vertical or set it as default(the user can stretch in both ways).

If you are setting `resize: horizontal` then you need to add the additional property as `max-width:200px;`

If you are setting `resize: vertical` then you need to add the additional property as `max-height:200px;`

Comment: Your code snippet pertaining to horizontal resizing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mishsx You need to increase the `max-width` of a textarea in order to stretch it more. I just have provided the sample width

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
resize:none
```

to restrict the resizing of a `textarea`.