# How can I stop text area growing beyond length of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code that I use to automatically resize a `textarea` as a user types in it. Is there a way to get it to stop when it gets to the bottom of the screen?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<style>
    .modalTextArea{
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1; 
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="modal-content">          
        <textarea class='modalTextArea' rows = 2 style='width: 100%'></textarea>
    </div>
    <script src = 'js/script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$('.modalTextArea').on('keyup', function(e){
    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight + 10);
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, your `<style>` element should be inside the `<head>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204584/how-to-restrict-max-textarea-width-and-height-in-chrome-or-how-to-disable-textar

Comment: It's pretty weird it grows everytime the user pressed a key

Comment: it will only grow when the scroll height changes, which is when Enter is hit or the text moves on to a new line

Comment: @gurvinder372 - Is the only way to do it to assign a fixed value? Is there any way to be able to dynamically figure out where the screen ends and get it to stop there? Sorry if that sounds crazy I dont know anything about this and am just trying to figure out what can and cant be done. Thanks

Comment: @discodowney you can check if the offset-top of textarea is same as screen height

Comment: Set `max-height` style attribute to your `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to compute the line height of a line in the textarea and to use this value in the keyup event:

```js
function getTextAreaLineHeight(className) {
  var element = $('.' + className);
  var txtSaved = element.text();
  var lineHeight = element.css('font-size', '12px').css('line-height', '1.25').text('x').height();
  element.text(txtSaved);
  return lineHeight;
}

$(function () {
  var txtAreaLineHeight = getTextAreaLineHeight('modalTextArea');
  $('.modalTextArea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (($(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) < ($(window).height() - txtAreaLineHeight)) {
      $(this).css('height', 'auto');
      $(this).height(this.scrollHeight + 10);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modalTextArea{
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-content">
    <textarea class='modalTextArea' rows = 2 style='width: 100%'></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the [height of HTML document](http://api.jquery.com/height/), you can use the following snippet:

```
$( document ).height();
```

As textarea increases its size each time an enter key is pressed, the html height also increases. So what you need to do is just to get the initial html height, in other words, outside your event handler, and then use an if clause:

```
var htmlHeight = $( document ).height();

$('.modalTextArea').on('keyup', function(e){
    var elementHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    if( htmlHeight > elementHeight ) {
      $(this).css('height', 'auto');
      $(this).height(this.scrollHeight +10);
    }
});
```